# Creating a Palindrome String Checker C++ using Arrays and No Pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, string, palindrome

Sorry if this seems really noobish and all, and the fact is, i've only been studying this for about a month now. I can't seem to get this to work right, wondering if any of you can help me out. The program once compiled only says that the inputted words are "not palindrome" even if they are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isPal (char[], int);

int main ()
{
  const int size = 10;
  int flag = 0;
  char arr[size];

  cout << "Enter Word\n";
  cin.getline(arr,10);
  flag = isPal(arr, size);

  if (flag == true)
    cout << "Word is Palindrome\n";
  else
    cout << "Not Palindrome\n";
  return 0;
}

bool isPal (char arr [],int size)
{
int q = 0;
char arr2[size];
for (int i = 0;i < size - 1; i++)
{
    arr2[i] = arr[9 - q]; //here I attempt to reverse arr1 and assign each element to arr2
    q++;
}
for (int j = 0; j < size - 1; j++)
{
   if (arr [j] != arr2[j])
   return false;
}
   return true
}
```

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but your program is using pointers. The `arr` inside `isPal` is exactly that.

Comment: I haven't studied what a pointer is, so I guess i've been using them unknowingly.

Comment: This might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106295/palindrome-program. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285432/to-find-if-a-given-string-is-palindrome-or-is-not-palindrome

Comment: To start with, you don't define `arr` or `size` in `main`. What are they? How do you determine the value of `size`? Why do you need to copy the array in order to check if it's a palindrome? What if the word is not 9 characters?

Comment: sorry about that. i defined them in my original code, i just neglected to copy them here. But I added them now.  The word size doesn't concern me at the moment, I can change that later. The word i'm using as a test is "racecar" Until I can figure out what concept i'm not grasping here, then I'll worry about the size.

Comment: Reverse the string using a grapheme cluster aware Unicode algorithm. Compare the result with the original. If they match, you got a palindrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to use plain C arrays then check with below code:-

```
bool isPallindrome ( char *p, int size ) //Remember here size must be one character before null                    //terminator.
{
char *begin, *end;
begin = p;
end = p + size;
while ( begin != end )
{
 if( *begin != *end )
   break;
 begin++;
 end--;
}
if ( begin != end )
  return false;
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize the arr2
2. Use `strlen` to know the length you Input rather than use `size`, because your input data is not always fixed in 10

In your original code:

```
input: 1234567
*arr => "1234567\0"
*arr2 => "??\07654321"
```

3. Use `size` replaced by `q`

> ```
> bool isPal (char arr [],int size)
> {
>   //q=0;                                    /* modified 3 */
>   char arr2[size] = "";                     /* modified 1 */
>   for (int i=0; i<strlen(arr); i++)         /* modified 2 */
>   {
>       arr2[i] = arr[strlen(arr)-i-1];       /* modified 2 */
>       //q++;                                /* modified 3 */
>   }
>   for (int i=0; i<strlen(arr); i++)         /* modified 2 */
>   {
>       if (arr[i] != arr2[i])
>           return false;
>   }
>   return true
> }
> ```

---

Array is "a pointer point to begin of array address", But for newbie, it's not easy to know how it works. You can reserve this thread until you learn the chapter `pointer`

Following the example of modified original code:

```
char arr[size];
char arr2[size];
// char *parr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);
// char *parr2 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

cin.getline(arr,10); 
// parr = &arr[0];
// cin.getline(parr, 10);

arr2[i] = arr[9 - q];
// parr1 = &arr[9-q];
// parr2 = &arr2[i]
// *parr2 = *parr1;

if (arr [j] != arr2[j])
// parr1 = &arr[j]
// parr2 = &arr2[j]
// if (*parr1 != *parr2)
```